# How to assign arbitrary x-axis value in R for a barplot?

Tags: r, plot, axis

I wish to make a barplot in R with 1000 vertical bars based on a list of numbers. Then, I want the resulting graph to have an x-axis that is labeled 1-10, evenly spaced underneath the 1000 columns. However, I only can figure out how to label every single column instead of the method I want. Here is my current code:

```
scores <- c(my 1000 data points)
barplot(scores, main="my plot", xlab="my 1000 scores", names.arg=c("list of 1-10"))
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to have the format of X-axis I desire? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by naming the 'scores' in the right places

```
scores <- sample(1000)
names(scores)<-NA
names(scores)[seq(1, 1000, 111)]<-1:10
barplot(scores, main="my plot", xlab="my 1000 scores")
```

**How does this work?**

We'll break down this line:

```
names(scores)[seq(1, 1000, 111)] <- 1:10
```

We've already assigned a name to every value in 'scores' (NA)

I can call those names with `names(scores)` and I can call subsets of those names with `names(scores)[1:10]`

Now for `seq(1, 1000, 111)` - this is a sequence from 1 to 1000 in steps of 111

So `names(scores)[seq(1, 1000, 111)]` is a subset of the names of 'scores' - specifically numbers 1, 112, 223 etc.

Why did i use 111? We are trying to space 10 values equally over 1000 'slots'. You calculate the steps with (1000 - 1) / (10 - 1)

For your second example (10 to 100 in steps of 10) we can simply replace `<-1:10` with a different set of numbers `seq(10, 100, 10)`

Notice that `length(1:10)` and `length(seq(10, 100, 10))` are both 10

Now for your final example `length(seq(0, 100, 10))`

By including 0, you have added an extra value (11 in total) so we need to use different slots in `names(scores)`

(1000 - 1)/(11-1) = 99.9 so we need to reset the names

```
names(scores) <- NA
```

then set the names with the new sequence

```
names(scores)[seq(1, 1000, 99.9)]<-seq(0, 100, 10)
```

Comment: Ed, how would I edit the line `names(scores)[seq(1, 1000, 111)]<-1:10` to make the scale from 10 to 100 instead of 1 to 10?

Comment: names(scores)[seq(1, 1000, 111)]<-seq(10, 100, 10)

Comment: last question Ed (sorry, i'm doing my best to understand the code), how about 0-100 in intervals of 10? I understand the code for the most part, but my following try didn't work: `names(scores_[seq(1,1000,100)] <- seq(0,100,10);

Answer (score 1):

The x-Position of each bar is returned by the function itself. So just use `xpos <- barplot(...)`. The y-Values you may calculate from `par('usr')`

or you use `axis`

```
tmp <- barplot(scores, main="my plot", xlab="my 1000 scores", names.arg=c(""))
axis(1,at=seq(min(tmp),max(tmp),len=10),lab=1:10)
```

Comment: Hi Jorg, thanks for the help. Can you please be a little more specific how to use `xpos <- barplot(..)` to my advantage? I'm an R novice.